# How do I calculate sum of column data for each row ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, relational-database

How do I calculate total of a column from each row ?

Such that if I have a ***Cost*** column and it has data in each row than I want to calculate its sum at the end, grouped by particular column and satisfying to particular condition.

I tried:

```
SELECT
       [SchemeName]
      ,SUM(CAST([SchemeCost] as INT)) as COST
      ,[SchemeHolderName]
      ,[SchemeApprovedBy]
  FROM [WMS_MCP].[dbo].[Schemes]
  Where SchemeHolderName like '%'+ 'Hussain' +'%'
  Group By SchemeCost,SchemeName,SchemeHolderName,SchemeApprovedBy

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
       ''
      ,SUM(CAST([SchemeCost] as INT)) as COST
      ,''
      ,''
  FROM [WMS_MCP].[dbo].[Schemes]
  Where SchemeHolderName like '%'+ 'Hussain' +'%'
  Group By SchemeCost,SchemeName,SchemeHolderName,SchemeApprovedBy
```

but it doesn't produce the desired output, I want a last row empty having only TOTALCOST in it.

Comment: And what is the result of  your querry and whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Group by clause from second select statement in union

```
    SELECT
   [SchemeName]
  ,SUM(CAST([SchemeCost] as INT)) as COST
  ,[SchemeHolderName]
  ,[SchemeApprovedBy]
  FROM [WMS_MCP].[dbo].[Schemes]
  Where SchemeHolderName like '%'+ 'Hussain' +'%'
  Group By SchemeCost,SchemeName,SchemeHolderName,SchemeApprovedBy

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
   ''
  ,SUM(CAST([SchemeCost] as INT)) as COST
  ,''
  ,''
  FROM [WMS_MCP].[dbo].[Schemes]
  Where SchemeHolderName like '%'+ 'Hussain' +'%'
```

Comment: because you are expecting total cost in last row, but by using group by result will be grouped by fields used in group by clause. and by just removing group by clause you will get sum of all rows from the table(cost will not be divided into group fields)